# How to Insert mp4 into gtk.TextBuffer pygtk 2.0

Tags: textview, pygtk, mp4, gtk-textbuffer

Using pygtk 2.0.

I know that I can insert an image into a gtk.TextBuffer() but I'm unable to find anything about inserting a small mp4.

I thought of an animated gif instead (if that is even possible), but I think they want to use the mp4 file instead.

If anyone knows, please advise. Thanks well in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gathered available on the Internet, you cannot embed a mp4 into a gtk.TextBuffer. You can embed an image such as png.

One would need to embed it in a widget like a table or frame and then send a command to the terminal to launch a mp4 player that plays the video.